# Prohibit HashSet to allow duplicate object in JAVA

Tags: java, equals, hashset, hashcode

In Main

```
Student st=new Student(1,"snack");
Student st1=new Student(2,"jack");
Student st2=new Student(2,"jack");
Set<Student> hs=new HashSet<Student>();
hs.add(st);
hs.add(st1);
hs.add(st2);    
System.out.println(hs);
```

O/P:[1 snack, 2 jack, 2 jack]

In Student

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.id;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Student obj) {

    if(this.id==obj.id)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
```

My objective is not to allow student who has the same id..name can be the same. Please provide details how HashSet checks which element is a duplicate?
All I know that HashSet returns true or false based on hashcode() and equals() method. **What works in back end?**

Comment: `public boolean equals(Student obj)` does not override `Object.equals`. It should rather be `public boolean equals(Object obj)`

Comment: Do I need to override both equals and hashcode? or only hashcode is enough?

Comment: You must override both.

Comment: Your code as posted doesn't compile.

Comment: If you use your IDE to generate your hashCode and equals it will be right or a good starting point. You can also use your IDE for getters, setters and toString.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got the condition reversed. You have to return `true` if two students have the same id.

```
if(this.id == obj.id)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

You are not overriding the `equals` in the `Object` class([`Object.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)). The `equals` takes an `Object` as a parameter and not `Student`.

Here's a way you can do it.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Student))
        return false;
    if (obj == this)
        return true;
    return this.id == ((Student) obj).id;
}
```

Comment: Your null check is redundant; `instanceof` takes care of that already.

Comment: @chrylis You are right. Changed it. Thanks

Comment: this.id == ((Student) obj).id please explain this line? which id is compared to which id?

Comment: It is same as your code. It compares the id of the object on which equals is invoked on with the id of the object that we are comparing against for equals.